# Call Java methods pending on DB values?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm currently working on an admin panel for some java programs I've written. The Java Programs are currently getting controlled by their own cfg files. My idea to update the configs via the control panel is to change values in the control panel, save those changes in a database via mysql and then write a "config updater" which keeps fetching the database entries every couple of seconds and then writes the changes to the cfg files. I'm just wondering about the efficency, is this a good approach or are there way better and more efficent ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you actually want to achieve.

If your program is reading the cfg files on demand, meaning, that you can change them and the results are effective immediately, you would just fetch them on demand from the DB as well.

If the cfg files are more or less statics, you might consider using a `.properties` file instead (or even a Config class containing only `static` and `final` fields), or, if you want to stick to the database, you could use the `Singleton` approach and just read it after startup into the `Singleton`.

In the end it's almost down to opinion and use-case. If the config should be configurable by the customer / end user, it might be better to use a database anyway. But as a developer, I frankly don't care as long as it's documented where to configure it.